# Latitude 5591 Won't Boot Unless Power Cord Connected

Tags: ubuntu, boot, laptop, dell-latitude

I've been using Latitude 5591 for around 4 months now and it's just great. I have a problem that started two-three days ago. The laptop doesn't boot unless the power cord is connected on boot. Details follows.

A couple days ago, Ubuntu Software Center showed with a message that a firmware update is available. I accepted the update. The very next restart, the BIOS was updating and it completed successful. Since then the laptop doesn't boot unless the power cord is connected.

When I hit the power button, one of two scenarios happen:

- Scenario A: Ubuntu's mauve/purple loading screen shows and it's stuck there.
- Scenario B: Grub menu shows a list of options (Ubuntu, Advanced Ubuntu Options, System Settings). When I choose Ubuntu, scenario A starts. Whenever I choose any kernel option from the advanced options, scenario A starts.

Now, if I have the power cable connected, Ubuntu boots right away.

Battery life is just fine. I can unplug the power cable after booting and everything is working as expected.

Shedding some light as to what the problem is and how to get it solved would be much appreciated.

I'm using GNU/Linux 18.04.4 LTS.

I'm not sure if this question fits here perfectly or other forums would be better. If you think I should post this somewhere else, please point out the forum to post to.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the details of the BIOS update and whenever it might be a known bug? Did you manually check if there is another update available?

Comment: What *details* you specifically mean? How can I know if it's a known bug? Yes, I checked there're no more updates to install.

Comment: The details of what it actually changes. Did you just check your repo or the actual source from Dell? Did you check whenever Dell has put up some kind of information about an issue with that particular update?

Comment: I checked the actual source from Dell, their updates page. [This](https://www.dell.com/support/home/in/en/inbsd1/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=d52gm&oscode=biosa&productcode=latitude-15-5591-laptop) is the update I'm talking about.

Comment: @Ask to Dell too; maybe they will find that is a bug and then release a new firmware version.

Comment: I'm contacting dell to communicate this issue. Will post the solution, if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to roll back the Bios update, [Dell has all the previous versions](https://www.dell.com/support/home/in/en/indhs1/product-support/product/latitude-15-5591-laptop/drivers), its best to roll back to the version you had, if you remember.

When the page loads, click on the bios update title and it will expand, then click "older versions"

.

.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Doesn't rolling back mean missing the urgent update?

Comment: @joker Yes, but at least you don't have issues with the "Modified battery algorithm to prolong lifespan and minimize risk of swelling."

Comment: I never update my bios unless there is a feature upgrade I need.

Comment: Downgrading solved the problem. It seems like it's a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same thing on my dual booting Latitude 5591 (KDE Neon based on 18.04 LTS).

I just had success following the fix suggested for the [Precision 7540](https://www.dell.com/community/Precision-Mobile-Workstations/Precision-7540-will-only-boot-Linux-if-charger-is-connected/m-p/7506203/highlight/true#M3064):

1. Edit your GRUB settings:

   ```
   sudoedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Find the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` setting and add the option `dis_ucode_ldr`:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash dis_ucode_ldr"
   ```

   (You may have other unrelated options set as well.)
3. Save and run:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

You should then be able to shutdown and restart without the power cable connected.